# Is it possible to configure a grafana alert (notification channel) with yaml inside an application's charts?

Tags: notifications, prometheus, grafana, kubernetes-helm

I just finished adding a dashboard to my app's helm charts that basically looks like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: grafana-dashboard-my-app-dashboard
  namespace: monitoring
  labels:
    grafana_dashboard: "1"
data:
  my-app-dashboard.json: |
    --- EXPORTED DASHBOARD JSON HERE ---
```

My dashboard has an alert configured in it.  In the exported dash JSON, there is a reference to the notification channel for this alert:

```
          "notifications": [
          {
            "uid": "slack_my_app"
          }
```

Unfortunately, I haven't had much luck adding a yaml file to my app's charts that represents this notification channel (essentially just a slack url).

The documentation here makes me think that configuring these channels only happens with the grafana charts (not with the charts for my application): https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/provisioning/#alert-notification-channels

Does anyone know if its possible to include my notification channel configuration along with my dashboard configuration (with my application's charts)?  It seems a little strange that I can add the configuration for the dashboard and alert directly to my app's charts but not provide the notification channel as well.

Comment: You cannot do it because multiple dashboards usually use the same notification channels.

Comment: Shoot.  I was hoping that wasn't the case.  Thanks for your comment, @trallnag

Comment: @chrismead have fount the soluton how to configure notification channel separately?

Comment: @IlyaYevlampiev unfortunately, no... I never found a way to configure the notification channel (aside from manually)

Comment: @chrismead I got the answer in my question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68454146/1759063