# How to add Grafana's provisioned notification channel in kube-prometheus-stack?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, grafana-alerts, kube-prometheus-stack

I'm looking for example, how to set up the provisioned notification channel and it's uid in the helm chart https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus

The dashboards are referencing the notification channel, but what is the sample yaml to add the notification channel itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example YAML file : https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/main/conf/provisioning/notifiers/sample.yaml

If you are using the HELM chart for same you can configure same from the **values.yaml**

Example : https://github.com/devnulled/charts/blob/24f03dafab2f05f01f6316ba78f9de04adb02f3b/stable/grafana/values.yaml

```
notifiers: {}
#  notifiers.yaml:
#    notifiers:
#    - name: email-notifier
#      type: email
#      uid: email1
#      # either:
#      org_id: 1
#      # or
#      org_name: Main Org.
#      is_default: true
#      settings:
#        addresses: an_email_address@example.com
#    delete_notifiers:
```

Documentation : https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/provisioning/#alert-notification-channels

Commit details : https://github.com/devnulled/charts/commit/24f03dafab2f05f01f6316ba78f9de04adb02f3b

Comment: currenty I'm getting `coalesce.go:200: warning: cannot overwrite table with non table for notifiers (map[])` warning

Comment: I has missed two lines `notifiers.yaml:  notifiers:` when was uncommenting them, that's why